# Graphql rest controller

Tags: java, spring, graphql-java

I am new to graphql. I want to implement backend in spring boot using graphql. I am still confused about endpints. So if i have 2 entities user and product. so do i have to implement 2 endpoints

```
@RequestMapping(value="/graphql/user", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public GraphQLResponse<Object> getService(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestBody GraphQLRequest graphql) {
    GraphQLResponse<Object> execute = graphQLService.execute(headers, graphql);
    return execute;

}
```

like this one for user and another one for product. or just one.

Answer (score 3):

No you need only one Endpoint. I suggest you to use this library. With this library it is very easy to start into the world of GraphQL:
https://github.com/leangen/GraphQL-SPQR

And a good example with this library and Springboot you find here, just clone the repo and run it local:
https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples

Install this Plugin in Chrome to get read and query your schema easely:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeiql/fkkiamalmpiidkljmicmjfbieiclmeij

I hoped this answer helped you.

Comment: Instead of providing links only please add some examples of possible solution(s).

Answer (score 1):

With spring-boot-grpahql, there's no need to write controller at all. You just need to write ORM layer rest will be taken care by it. 
[Here's](https://github.com/thekosmix/GraphQL-SpringBoot) an example implementation of GraphQL in java using spring-boot, gradle, spring-jpa and mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Graphql exposes only one endpoint and depending on your setup it may be accessible like this: `http://localhost:8080/graphql`. Usually you never access graphql directly but rather via libraries that perform actions that allow you to communicate with graphql (like type-checking, converting between graphql types and your types and more).

[Java GraphQL Kickstart](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart) is one of them and all you do is define schema and write resolvers for your queries, mutations and subscriptions:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  allUsers: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String!
}
```

And your resolver:

```java
package your.project.resolvers;

import graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import your.project.domain.persistence.User;
import your.project.repository.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver  {

   private final UserRepository userRepository;

   // be carefull about the name of this method
   public List<User> allUsers() {
      // perform actions based on your needs
      return userRepository.findAll();
   }
}
```

Notice that I'm using service annotation because this is basically performing some business logic on data retrieved from persistence layer. Also the name of the method `allUsers()` in the `UserResolver` is important. GraphQL will look for it based on your schema like this:

- trying exact match with `allUsers`
- prepending `get`: `getAllUsers`